# JQuery Absolute Positioned elements / differing user resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My issue is very closely related to the following:

[Heat Map on different screen resolution using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421566/heat-map-on-different-screen-resolution-using-jquery)

Basically I have a system whereby users can leave annotations across a website. JQuery provides me with the top and left co ords for these. I can store these inside a database and then recall them. Problem is these annotations appear out of place on resolutions which the original annotations were note set at.

Any ideas / tips how I might over come this?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out where an annotation is relative to the nearest object on your page and record the location of the annotation as an offset from that object and then reconstruct that position when you position the annotation later.  This isn't guaranteed to be exact, but it will not have a large position error vs. the original.

Unless you're going to manually layout your page yourself (not let the browser control it) or position everything in pixels, browser layout is not designed to be 100% identical on all screens (that's why we have formats like PDF).